# test case writing in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

```
[HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Create() //loads the form
        {
            var categoryList = new SelectList(new[] { "Electronics", "Toys","Books","Sporting Goods"}); //defines the categories
            ViewBag.CategoryList = categoryList;
            return View();
        }
```

I write a test method for this..

```
[TestMethod]

        public void TestCreate() {

            AdvertisementController controller = new AdvertisementController();
            var categoryList = new SelectList(new[] { "Electronics", "Toys", "Books", "Sporting Goods" });
            ViewResult result = controller.Create() as ViewResult;
            Assert.AreEqual(categoryList,result.ViewBag.categoryList);

        }
```

but it's failed.I want to know what's the case.what wrong of this??

Comment: What does the failure say?

Comment: Please describe exactly what's wrong (compile error? Exception? Paste the exact message you're seeing). Also, change `new[]` to `new string[]`.

Comment: i think you have asked similar question about half an hour ago ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173200/how-to-write-a-test-case-to-check-return-view

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ . Fail means unit test is failed !!!!

Comment: yeah test failed.this not means code incorrect.what should i do to pass the test???

Comment: @RameshRajendran there are many reasons why a Unit Test can fail. It's important when asking a question to describe the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCreate() {

        // Setup
        AdvertisementController controller = new AdvertisementController();
        ViewResult result = controller.Create() as ViewResult;

        var expectedCategories = new SelectList(new[] { "Electronics", "Toys", "Books", "Sporting Goods" }).ToList();

        // Execute
        var actualCategories = result.ViewBag.categoryList.ToList();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[0], actualCategories[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[1], actualCategories[2]);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[2], actualCategories[3]);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[3], actualCategories[4]);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[4], actualCategories[5]);

    }
```

Basically in this, you're verifying that result is equal to something, and that EACH item within the array matches the expected item.

*note: I didn't wire this up in an IDE so it might have some mistakes.*

Comment: I tried this but it gives this error.Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Comment: ah, I missed that. You probably need to do a `typeof` comparison. Also, I would ABSOLUTELY NOT pass a SelectList via the ViewBag. Please for the love of all things pure and holy, create a ViewModel.

Comment: I made a small edit. Maybe by adding `.ToList()` on the SelectList will give you the Value comparison that you need... again, untested... no IDE to work on.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Comment: How to compare two SelectList items

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what's going on here, but it seems that the test is comparing that the exact instance of the `SelectList` is used in the MVC action and in the unit test.

You should instead compare that each *item* in the SelectList is the same.