# MVC unit testing for Viewbag dropdown items returned from controller to view

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which gets Roles from DB & assigns to a dropdown

```
 var items = (entities.tbllogins.GroupBy(a => a.Role).Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault())).ToList();//get count 
        ViewBag.drpitems = new SelectList(items, "Role", "Role");
        return View();
```

In a View I have,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Role, (SelectList)ViewBag.drpitems, "Choose")
```

> Now i wanted to write test case in my project for this scenario, I have tried

```
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        var result = controller.Login() as ViewResult;

        var expectedCategories = new SelectList(new[] { "Admin", "User"});
        // Execute
        var actualCategories = (SelectList)result.ViewBag.drpitems;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.Count(), actualCategories.Count());
        for (var i = 0; i < expectedCategories.Count(); i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.ElementAt(i).Value, actualCategories.ElementAt(i).Value);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.ElementAt(i).Text, actualCategories.ElementAt(i).Text);
        }
```

I have referred [test case writing in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173499/test-case-writing-in-c-sharp) for the same,along with this also i have read many articles & blogs. But no success so far.
Test says failed.
Could anyone please help me where i missed in writing test case

Thanks

Comment: Where does the test fail? Which Assert?

Comment: i got this error "Failed Login TestDemo_MVCApplication.Tests Test method TestDemo_MVCApplication.Tests.UnitTest1.Login threw exception"

Comment: Have you debugged the unit test? There must be a line of code that is causing the exception.